# Fatal error: AudioKit: Could not start engine. AudioKit.start()

Tags: audiokit

```
import UIKit

import Photos

import AudioKit

import AudioKitUI

class VoicesController: CaptureContentController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nodeOutputPlot: AKNodeOutputPlot!

    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func recordButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        guard let phase = event.allTouches?.first?.phase else {
            return
        }

        if phase == .began {
            try? nodeRecorder.record()
        }

        if phase == .ended {
            nodeRecorder.stop()

            try? audioPlayer.reloadFile()

            let fileName = NSUUID().uuidString + ".wav"
            audioPlayer.audioFile.exportAsynchronously(name: fileName, baseDir: .documents, exportFormat: .wav, callback: { [weak self] (audioFile, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(#line, error)

                    return
                }

                //                // FIXME:
                //                if let url = audioFile?.avAsset.url {
                //                    _ = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: url)!
                //                    // creationRequest.location
                //                }

                if let fileName = audioFile?.avAsset.url.lastPathComponent {
                    let asset = VPFAsset()
                    asset.mediaType = .audio
                    asset.urlString = fileName
                    asset.thumbUrlString = ""

                    self?.captureDelegate?.append(asset)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    var audioPlayer: AKAudioPlayer!

    var nodeRecorder: AKNodeRecorder!

    var micMixer: AKMixer!

    var mainMixer: AKMixer!

    var booster: AKBooster!

    var moogLadder: AKMoogLadder!

    let microphone = AKMicrophone()

    @objc func didBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
        AudioKit.start()
    }



@objc func willResignActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    AudioKit.stop()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    AKAudioFile.cleanTempDirectory()

    AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium

    do {
        try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true

    nodeOutputPlot.node = microphone
    micMixer = AKMixer(microphone)
    booster = AKBooster(micMixer)

    booster.gain = 0
    nodeRecorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: micMixer)
    if let audioFile = nodeRecorder.audioFile {
        audioPlayer = try? AKAudioPlayer(file: audioFile)
        audioPlayer.completionHandler = {
            print(#line)
        }
    }

    moogLadder = AKMoogLadder(audioPlayer)
    mainMixer = AKMixer(moogLadder, booster)
    AudioKit.output = mainMixer

    AudioKit.start()

    NotificationCenter.default
        .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default
        .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

deinit {
    print("deinit VoicesController")

    AudioKit.stop()

    NotificationCenter.default
        .removeObserver(self)
}
```

}

Hello, my English is not good, I am a Chinese, I really like AudioKit, because it is convenient, but in the recent system update, I encountered a crashes, but not always crashes, it seems that only collapse once, After that no crashes, I made a screenshot, because the system does not always update, hoping to get help，thank you very much，I am a novice, please advise

[这是截图](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR0L0.png)

Thread 1: Fatal error: AudioKit: Could not start engine. error: Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-10875 "(null)" UserInfo={failed call=err = AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInOutputChain(ThisGraph, kOutputChainOptimizedTraversal, *GetOutputNode(), isOutputChainActive)}.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest develop branch (not yet released), you have to wrap AudioKit.start() in a do try catch block

```
do {
    try AudioKit.start()
} catch {
    AKLog("Something went wrong.")
}
```

All of the examples included with AudioKit show how to implement this change.